Is there a way to execute forms in parallel in Common Lisp? Something like a parallel PROGN?
I have a sequence of array assignments:
...
(incf (aref res 1) formula1)
(incf (aref res 2) formula2)
...

The formulai is some complicated auto-generated code, and it's very different for each i. This code is generated at compile time - it's an algebraic expression, not a macro or function.
What I want is to wrap these statements in something like a "parallel progn", so that the assignments are partitioned onto different worker threads. The order of execution doesn't matter since each index is assigned exactly once.
I can't see how to fit this problem into lparallel's abstractions, but maybe I'm missing something. It seems that neither pmap, plet, nor futures are a good fit for this problem.

There are no standard parallel programming features in Common Lisp, but there may be implementation-specific extensions or third-party libraries.

Search your implementation's documentation for multithreading.

@Barmar Sure, but I'm looking for something like Bordeaux Threads or lparallel - a library construct or something made from a library construct that has widespread support.

Turns out there is such a package available. Investigating the ones listed by (ql:system-apropos "parallel") led me to simple-parallel-tasks, which includes a pprogn form, documented as

Evaluate forms in parallel and return the result of the evaluation of the last form.

(There's also a pprog1 which returns the first form).

Thank you! For anyone who sees this, simple-parallel-tasks is a slick one-file library that depends on chanl. It's worth taking the time to understand the code. It may be possible to write a leaner function than pprogn that's analogous to (map nil ...) that doesn't bother storing return values by using chanl. I plan to do this since the forms I'm evaluating are state mutations that can be safely evaluated in a non-blocking parallel algorithm.
